# Broken SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a database query that works perfect;

```
SELECT 
    campaigns.cid, campaigns.aid, campaigns.weburl, CampCount 
FROM 
    campaigns 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         adtracking.cid, count(*) AS CampCount 
     FROM adtracking 
     WHERE adtracking.createdate = [todays date] 
     GROUP BY adtracking.cid ) AS adtracking ON campaigns.cid = adtracking.cid 
WHERE 
    campaigns.catid = '1' 
    AND campaigns.campaigncomplete = '0' 
    AND campaigns.active = '1' 
    AND (adtracking.cid IS NULL OR CampCount < campaigns.dailynumberofimpressions) 
ORDER BY 
    RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

1st the advertises table is a one to many of the campaigns. So it;s on advertiser to many campaigns. aid is te advertiser id and that is the link to the campaign table. cid is the campaign id.

A new field was just put into the advertiseter table called adminstop and it can have values of "0" for false and "1" for true. If this claue is true than ALL of the campaigns for this aid will no longer run.

So i was attempting to put into the query

```
where campaign.cid in (select cid from advertisers where aid.adminstop = '0')
```

I am having no luck whatsoever. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

jeff Goldstein

Comment: It's pretty hard to read from this kind of formatting. Could you put it in the 'code' block? What is the error you are getting? Looking at your query, you should have rather 'where compains.cid ...' as that's the alias you're using in your query

Comment: *Broken SQL query* is meaningless. It's clear the question is about SQL from the tag, and it's clear it's broken or you wouldn't be posting here. Please [edit] your question title to something that is descriptive enough to have use to future readers here if it turns up in a search result. Also, I don't see where you've attempted to do any such thing, and I don't see anything that explains why you're having difficulty in doing so. *I am having no luck* is not a problem description that is useful to us.

Comment: I also might be mistaken, but you don't have any 'advertisers' table, but adtracking only. And if you put 'compaigns' instead of 'campaign' into your query, it works fine for me. What is the sql engine you are using?

Comment: what is "aid.adminstop"? you probably mean just "adminstop", don't you?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: An advertiser record has an adminstop flag which when set would mean that all the advertiser's compaigns are stopped? How then does this advertiser table have one single compaign ID (cid)? This makes no sense. Please show all table definitions and tell us what "I am having no luck" is supposed to mean.